# Dependence of mass transfer coefficient on solubility

Tags: physical-chemistry, solubility, chemical-engineering

Does solubility of the solute affect the value of the mass transfer coefficient?

The book I am following mentions that the mass transfer coefficient is a characteristic of the constituent and its environment, and solubility is a property of the environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No.**

In all but highly exotic situations, diffusive and convective fluxes of solutes are linear in the solution-phase concentration of the species:

$$
\begin{align}
J &= -D {\mathrm dC\over \mathrm dx}  & \mathrm{(diffusion)} \\
N_c  &= k_c\left(C_\infty - C_\mathrm{surface} \right)  \quad & \mathrm{(convection)}
\end{align}
$$

Whatever the dissolved concentration $C$ (or concentration gradient ${\mathrm dC\over \mathrm dx}$) of the species is, that is the value you use in both of the above equations.  Whether that concentration (gradient) arises from a species with low, intermediate, or high solubility doesn't matter at all. I suspect your book is using the term *environment* to refer to things like the geometry, temperature, and fluid-flow characteristics of the system.

The main way I can think of where the solubility might affect the *overall mass transport* achievable in the system is in its effect on the maximum possible dissolved solute concentration at the surface.  If solubility limitations constrain $C_\mathrm{surface}$ to a low value, then the *magnitude of* $N_c$ will necessarily be low.  The low solubility is typically assumed not to appreciably change the value of $k_c$, however.